# Unable to declare local variables in VScode Mongo scrapbook

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode cosmosdb extension and have connected to an Atlas MongoDB. I can do db.movies.find() and get the data back ok. However, I can't declare local variables such as var foo=['nnn','mmm'] . This gives error "mis-matched input 'var' expecting EOF".

What is the syntax for declaring local variables in a MongoDB scrapbook in VSCode.